# Печень - печь

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Вчера задумалась, есть ли какая связь между словом "печь" (и производными - печенье и т.д.) и "печень". Вроде как печень не печёт. Почему-ж тогда так схоже?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Печень в буквальном смысле - это печенное (>жаренное). Такое значение у этого слова до сих пор сохранилось в польском, где печенью называют любое жаренное мясо. На Руси мясо чаще варили, но печень вкусна только в жаренном виде и видимо поэтому сперва за блюдом из органа, а затем и за самим органом закрепилось подобное слово.

Comment: А в словацкий как тогда попало?
Достаточно далекий все-таки от восточно-славянских язык, по сути - то же чешский, с немного другой орфографией.

Comment: Так печень везде ели только жаренной. По-чешски "реčеnkа" - жаркое.

Эта верия требует гораздо меньше допущений, чем ваша. Человеческую анатомию древние римляне может и знали, а вот в средние века с этим было худо. В XIX веке по церковно-приходским наиболее частые причины смерти "заспали младенца", "роды", "понос" под последним имелись в виду все болезни, которые завершались предсмертной дефекацией. НЕ поверю, что эти же люди смогли определить еле ощутимую разницу температуры.

Answer (score 2):

Печет. )))
Кажется, здесь это уже обсуждалась, но не могу сейчас искать, может, кто поможет.

Очень кратко.
Печень - это небольшой химический реактор. Температура печени у здорового человека обычно на градус-полтора выше температуры других внутрениих органов. А при некоторых заболевания - и больше. Это заметили еще древние римляне. По одной из версий - древние славяне тоже. Хотя, возможно, что название и унаследовано из праславянского, ибо сам корень - индоевропейский, но с тем же смыслом.
Другие версии допускают случайное созвучие, но все равно - с последующим переосмыслением.

Comment: Печень в буквальном смысле - это печенное (>жаренное). 

А почему "печеное" и "жареное" с двумя Н?